# Format/parse a string in Vb

Tags: regex, vb6, parsing, printing

I am working with some input that is in the possible forms

```
$1,200
20 cents/ inch
$10
```

Is there a way to parse these to numbers in VB?  Also printing these numbers?

**EDIT:** Regular expressions would be great.

**EDIT:** VB 6 in particular

Comment: I think you should be more explicit about what you expect for output. Is this what you would want?
$1,200         -> 1200
20 cents/ inch -> 20
$10            -> 10

Comment: Which VB do you want an answer for? VB.Net, VB6, VBA, or VBScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehh...Assuming all that you want is the digits, I would use a Regular Expression to simply replace any non-digit with "".

You would need to reference Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions in your project. Then let's say that your text was in a variable called strTest. Here is some off the cuff untested code:

```
Dim oRE As Object
Set oRE = New VBScript_RegExp.RegExp
oRe.Pattern = "\D"
strTest = oRE.Replace(strTest, "")
```

Comment: that would be fine, but can regular expressions get the pre text and post text ?

Answer (score 3):

You mean VB6/VBA or VB.net?
In VB6 or VBA you can do `CLng()`
Or `CDec()` depending on what type of number you want.
They will deal with the beginning dollar sign and commas just fine.
For dealing with the 20 cents / inch you should probably do something like

```
CLng(split("20 cents / inch", " ")(0))
```

These functions throw a type conversion error if they can't convert.
You can trap that and try converting it another way if they fail.

There is also a function called Val which returns the numeric portion.
It doesn't generate type conversion errors like `CDec`.  But it also doesn't handle any non-numeric input.  It gives you the decimal value of the digits in a string as long as it starts with a digit.  It ignores any trailing characters.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it just takes brute force!

Here is a routine that takes in a string with numbers and returns a number properly handled with fractions, M or B suffixes, and more.  You can modify i to handle any special condition or text algebra (miles / hour, cents / inch, etc)

This is taken from one of our production applications thus the line numbers which we use in our error handler (ERHandler), as well as the standard exit routine.

```
Function GetNumberFromString(s As String) As Currency
12800 Const ProcID = "GetNumberFromString"
12810 Dim c                                   As String
12820 Dim d                                   As Integer
12830 Dim Denominator                         As Double ' currency only handles 4 places
12840 Dim HaveDec                             As Boolean
12850 Dim HaveSlash                           As Boolean
12860 Dim HaveSpace                           As Boolean
12870 Dim i                                   As Integer
12880 Dim LenV                                As Integer
12890 Dim NegMult                             As Integer
12900 Dim Numerator                           As Currency
12910 Dim TempVal                             As Currency
12920 Dim v                                   As String

      'Provides the functionality of VAL, but handles commas, fractions
      ' also million and billion

12930 On Error GoTo ErrLbl
12940 oLog.LogProcEntry ModuleID, ProcID, "v=" & v

12950 v = Trim(s)
12960 LenV = Len(v)
12970 If LenV = 0 Then
12980     GetNumberFromString = 0
12990     GoTo ExitProc
13000 End If
13010 TempVal = 0
13020 d = 0
13030 NegMult = 1
      '
13040 For i = 1 To LenV
13050     c = Mid(v, i, 1)
13060     Select Case c
          Case "0" To "9"
13070         If HaveSpace Then
13080             If Not HaveSlash Then
13090                 Numerator = 10 * Numerator + Asc(c) - 48
13100             Else
13110                 Denominator = 10 * Denominator + Asc(c) - 48
13120             End If
13130         ElseIf Not HaveDec Then
13140             TempVal = 10 * TempVal + Asc(c) - 48
13150         Else
13160             TempVal = TempVal + ((Asc(c) - 48)) / (10 ^ d)
13170             d = d + 1
13180         End If
13190     Case ",", "$"
          ' do nothing
13200     Case "-" 'let handle negatives ns 12/20/96
13210         NegMult = -1 * NegMult
13220     Case "(" 'let handle negatives mt 6/9/99
13230         NegMult = -1 * NegMult
13240     Case "."
13250         HaveDec = True
13260         d = 1
13270     Case " "
13280         HaveSpace = True
13290         d = 1
13300     Case "/"
13310         HaveSlash = True
13320         If Not HaveSpace Then
13330             HaveSpace = True
13340             Numerator = TempVal
13350             TempVal = 0
13360         End If
13370     Case "b", "B"
13380         If UCase(Mid(v, i, 7)) = "BILLION" Then
13390             TempVal = TempVal * 1000000000#
13400             Exit For
13410         End If
13420     Case "m", "M"
13430         If UCase(Mid(v, i, 7)) = "MILLION" Then
13440             TempVal = TempVal * 1000000#
13450             Exit For
13460         End If
13470     Case Else
          ' ignore character/error
13480     End Select
13490 Next i

13500 If HaveSlash And Denominator <> 0 Then
13510     TempVal = TempVal + Numerator / Denominator
13520 End If

13530 GetNumberFromString = TempVal * NegMult

ExitProc:
13540 oLog.LogProcExit ModuleID, ProcID
13550 Exit Function

ErrLbl:
13560 Debug.Print Err.Description, Err.Number
13570 Debug.Assert False
13580 ERHandler ModuleID, ProcID
13590 Resume
End Function
```